# Jekyll can't find 'home' layout

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I have just started trying to use jekyll for github pages.

I wished to use the theme leap-day.
 Following the instructions, It just came up with some can not find post / can not find page errors, I followed the instruction ongithub to create `_layouts/page.html` and `_layouts/post.html`

Now I am finding it is complaining it can't find home layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jekyll theme `leap-day` has just one layout: `default.html` while most of the times the first Jekyll version uses `minima` who has three: `default`, `page` and `post`.

To properly use `leap-day` make all your pages/posts and home page use `layout: default`.